# Can't connect to Internet (Ethernet or WiFi) after 14.04 upgrade on ideaPad U530

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, ethernet, ubuntu-14.04, lenovo-laptop

I am currently unable to connect to the Internet on my newly upgraded Ubuntu 14.04. Network Manager is able to identify wireless networks, and it can detect when I'm plugged into an Ethernet connection, but it always seems to timeout when trying to connect. I've tried this both at work and at home and get the same results.

Here is a link to the output of `dmesg`: [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B75g0GKpBnaxa0lxenNjOVpOdTg/view?usp=sharing)

Here are some diagnostics:

User@Host:~$ sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 08:9e:01:da:a1:e3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.038.00-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:60 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2504000-b2504fff memory:b2500000-b2503fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 73
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:4a:af:79
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-36-generic firmware=25.222.9.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:62 memory:b2400000-b2401fff
```

User@Host:~$ ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:9e:01:da:a1:e3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:60 Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:224 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:17008 (17.0 KB)  TX bytes:17008 (17.0 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:8b:fd:4a:af:79  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e8b:fdff:fe4a:af79/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:43446 (43.4 KB)  TX bytes:50008 (50.0 KB)
```

User@Host:~$ route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

User@Host:~$ lspci -vnn | grep 8168

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
Kernel driver in use: r8168
```

User@Host:~$ lspci -vnn | grep 7260

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]
```

User@Host:~$ vim /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

User@Host:~$ vim /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

User@Host:~$ vim /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       Host

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
    ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
    fe00::0 ip6-localnet
    ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
    ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
    ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

User@Host:~$ vim /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

I feel like I have tried everything and am running out of options. Please let me know if anyone has any idea what to do from here.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the output of `dmesg` ?

One thing you might try is to modify your /etc/network/interfaces file to include:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

just after the loopback network interface entries.  In theory, this should allow automatic IP address assignment, given a DHCP-enabled router.

After making changes, run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: Hi dazzle, thanks so much for the help! I just updated the post above to include the output of dmesg in the form of a link to a Google Drive document. I tried modifying /etc/network/interfaces like you suggested but it still didn't work.